# Does CameraX fail to save EXIF rotation data in emulator?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am trying to take pictures using CameraX.

I am using `.setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)` on both the Preview and the ImageCapture.

I have tested with my Samsung Galaxy Tab E tablet and everything seems to work fine. The resulting image has an EXIF rotation value that makes sure the image is displayed properly.

Then I tried testing on an emulator (using a Pixel on API 23) just to see what another device would be like. In this case, the EXIF rotation value of the saved image is always 0, regardless of what `viewFinder.display.rotation` is.

So what I'm wondering is, is this an issue with the emulator not saving the EXIF data for some reason? Because if it's just the emulator that has challenges I don't care. But if it means that some devices that my users might use will have their images rotated incorrectly, that is unacceptable.

Comment: Testing on emulators (especially with older API levels) can result in some inconsistencies at times. Could you test on newer API levels? E.g. API levels 29 and 30.

Comment: I just tested it using even API 27 on the same emulated device (Pixel) and it seemed to work fine. It makes me wonder if the issue was with API 23 or just with the emulator... hopefully just the emulator.